# "standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"" when run gitlab by docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

got error "standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"" when run gitlab by docker on ROCK64.

here is the os,docker version information detail:
here is the os,docker version information detail:
here is the os,docker version information detail:

**runing script:**

```
#!/bin/sh sudo docker run -d 
--publish 30008:30008
--publish 30009:22
--name gitlab 
--restart always 
--volume /home/rock64/docker_gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab 
--volume /home/rock64/docker_gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
--volume /home/rock64/docker_gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab 
--env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG=" gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=30009;"  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

**os info:**

```
root@R1:/home/rock64# uname -a
Linux R1 4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136 #1 SMP Thu Oct 12 09:14:48 UTC 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@R1:/home/rock64# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136 (root@713b8312374e) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 12 09:14:48 UTC 2017
root@R1:/home/rock64# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l
root@R1:/home/rock64# file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=2ddaf2fd4461aedced3da6b946139afc66738025, stripped
```

**docker info:**

```
root@R1:/home/rock64#
docker info
Containers: 1
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: aarch64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.833GiB
Name: R1
ID: AWYP:CJI6:AKW5:4L5X:R5MQ:73K2:T5B6:MXFO:QX2C:SJFR:4EA7:PGWS
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

**docker version:**

```
root@R1:/home/rock64# docker version
Client:
Version:    17.12.0-ce
API version:    1.35
Go version: go1.9.2
Git commit: c97c6d6
Built:  Wed Dec 27 20:07:05 2017
OS/Arch:    linux/arm64
Server:
Engine:
Version:    17.12.0-ce
API version:    1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.9.2
Git commit: c97c6d6
Built:  Wed Dec 27 20:05:10 2017
OS/Arch:    linux/arm64
Experimental:   false
```

**docker inspect:**

```
root@R1:/home/rock64# docker inspect 5d8ab6b06918
[
{
    "Id": "sha256:5d8ab6b06918324513046b37467019d81d3994b8694234db177fcf47b7da8dde",
    "RepoTags": [
        "gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest"
    ],
    "RepoDigests": [
        "gitlab/gitlab-ce@sha256:4dcb6fc5cc75442dcf041c304d9b940f65bf1c0cdd06a7394201fec886fbd50e"
    ],
    "Parent": "",
    "Comment": "",
    "Created": "2018-04-03T16:57:19.588723941Z",
    "Container": "97625459f673be91b73f0066e714891207e08085f77736319d355c49ba148968",
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "Hostname": "97625459f673",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "22/tcp": {},
            "443/tcp": {},
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/opt/gitlab/bin:/assets:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "#(nop) ",
            "HEALTHCHECK &{[\"CMD-SHELL\" \"/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-healthcheck --fail\"] \"1m0s\" \"30s\" \"0s\" '\\x05'}"
        ],
        "Healthcheck": {
            "Test": [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-healthcheck --fail"
            ],
            "Interval": 60000000000,
            "Timeout": 30000000000,
            "Retries": 5
        },
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:d4830a3f9d0bae0137c4f08688698ca0b031ccf2820d54e40b179a60d639d1b5",
        "Volumes": {
            "/etc/gitlab": {},
            "/var/log/gitlab": {},
            "/var/opt/gitlab": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "Shell": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c"
        ]
    },
    "DockerVersion": "18.03.0-ce",
    "Author": "GitLab Inc. <support@gitlab.com>",
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "22/tcp": {},
            "443/tcp": {},
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/opt/gitlab/bin:/assets:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/assets/wrapper"
        ],
        "Healthcheck": {
            "Test": [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-healthcheck --fail"
            ],
            "Interval": 60000000000,
            "Timeout": 30000000000,
            "Retries": 5
        },
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:d4830a3f9d0bae0137c4f08688698ca0b031ccf2820d54e40b179a60d639d1b5",
        "Volumes": {
            "/etc/gitlab": {},
            "/var/log/gitlab": {},
            "/var/opt/gitlab": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": null,
        "Shell": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c"
        ]
    },
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Size": 1432825730,
    "VirtualSize": 1432825730,
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5946920efbd43f2233707a239bccc95364b360dc0fe0f97b1fcd75986b2fc473/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f1d5989329deb30b6e407aae30dbcf457495b4877f1ff7cd47fad1c64454f89/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9d7b87f67d6b08a4a0c378f9fa5d2720dfc76fa5f6b89b9fe578f5d5c32b7015/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15ee97ec37e4ae5204d79329489d75036743a3f2689f7670689012d2e900d547/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/981f017f379824a9fb4cc780dc4693a7798f3f81bdebd31b7ecbb49d0cd1ca22/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d016d87d04d76092ed76fdc2e60d4dc43246e47f6e74566fd32be23c8ed17127/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8a2a5f2c2efdc03c806fc3543f6d877abf2be807b83690eba6142b9d955e980f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/472ef38148dcdddad40f415bd43c9b31635d17b97f1044624253ef59974c21d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b8d1ec53e699e52970718aa656188d6ed4d3fae5d72395496c9568b582beb50/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4a6a20adfbed0002f610750db40bf79b19873e775f72bb44c7c9478e52ecb4cd/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f384698bf0dadd78cf3d2356cae49d70783b4510dcb6f1e9ecc33ade4f20fa/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f384698bf0dadd78cf3d2356cae49d70783b4510dcb6f1e9ecc33ade4f20fa/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f384698bf0dadd78cf3d2356cae49d70783b4510dcb6f1e9ecc33ade4f20fa/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:a94e0d5a7c404d0e6fa15d8cd4010e69663bd8813b5117fbad71365a73656df9",
            "sha256:88888b9b1b5b7bce5db41267e669e6da63ee95736cb904485f96f29be648bfda",
            "sha256:52f389ea437ebf419d1c9754d0184b57edb45c951666ee86951d9f6afd26035e",
            "sha256:52a7ea2bb533dc2a91614795760a67fb807561e8a588204c4858a300074c082b",
            "sha256:db584c622b50c3b8f9b8b94c270cc5fe235e5f23ec4aacea8ce67a8c16e0fbad",
            "sha256:548d2f3a8e505a5b1dec6d3bb963f8b21d61078103b1e1ef5d2f709435406666",
            "sha256:7a3c9d06807d32550e2f758f41a23d62513173ff63b33b22a9737a4d15a38c60",
            "sha256:abcc0971e3bc15b6647ad82a77a96dff10ebb24f28507998f1cb26b1e8689879",
            "sha256:7ec39eb738898ce3ff37aacf96ed9afb453ece7cc007eaf5fcd8873e2c9aeb68",
            "sha256:b654d3fb5f57f51e38dc7979aa8c620d21778cfc109ca1c304711e22bbf83119",
            "sha256:1c5b7dff198f70a3155ceeb496f998583c3bbff59d40fc5c64ce980416dea1a2"
        ]
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

]

Comment: The image's architecture (`"Architecture": "amd64"`) is not supported by your hardware.

Comment: so how can i make it work on my machine? change dockerfile to alpine?